# The word for serial maternalists?

Tags: word-choice, euphemisms

Consider the case where a woman goes from giving birth straight into pregnancy again and repeats the cycle.  Say five children in 46 months.

"She's a serial maternalist"? This doesn't sound right.

"She's a maternity serialist"? This doesn't sound right either.

How would you state this in a concise and socially elegant way?

Comment: "Pregnant is her normal state."

Answer (score 3):

Two siblings less than a year apart in age are called "Irish twins," so, possibly: "That woman has 'Irish quintuplets'"? (US)